# Apollo, Express, WS session not being shared

Tags: typescript, express, websocket, apollo-server, express-session

I'm using `ApolloServer` with `ExpressJS` and `WebSocket`. Additionally, I use `express-session` and `cookie-parser`. Somehow the `session` is not being shared between `Express` and `WebSocket`. I have already seen working examples out there but somehow my setup isn't working.

This is my middleware:

```
import cors = require('cors');
import expressSession = require('express-session');
import expressCookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import MongoStore from 'connect-mongo';
const SessionStore = MongoStore(expressSession);
export const allowOrigins = cors({
  credentials: true,
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
});

export const session = expressSession({
  store: new SessionStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }),
  secret: APP_SECRET,
  proxy: true,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: { secure: PRODUCTION },
});

export const cookieParser = expressCookieParser(APP_SECRET);
```

Apollo:

```
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import { schema, resolvers } from '../../graphql';

export const createApolloServer = () => {
  return new ApolloServer({
    introspection: APOLLO_INTROSPECTION,
    playground: APOLLO_PLAYGROUND,
    typeDefs: schema,
    resolvers,
    context: async (expressContext: ExpressContext) => {
      let session;
      if (expressContext.req) {
        session = expressContext.req.session; // different session here
        console.log('cookie express', expressContext.req.signedCookies)
      }
      if (expressContext.connection) {
        session = expressContext.connection.context.session; // different session here
        console.log('cookie websocket', expressContext.connection.context.request.signedCookies)
      }
      return <ResolverArgs>{
        expressContext,
        session,
      };
    },
    subscriptions: {
      onConnect: (params, websocket, context) => {
        const req = websocket.upgradeReq;
        const res = {} as any;
        return new Promise((rs, rj) => {
          cookieParser(req, res, () => {
            session(req, res, () => {
              console.log('share', req.session.id);
              rs({session: req.session});
            });
          });
        });
      },
    },
  });
};
```

Server initialization:

```
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
import { allowOrigins, session, cookieParser } from './middleware/basic';
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
app.use(allowOrigins);
app.use(cookieParser);
app.use(session);
const apollo = createApolloServer();
apollo.applyMiddleware({
  app,
  path: GRAPHQL_PATH,
  cors: false,
});
apollo.installSubscriptionHandlers(server);
```

I can see cookies are sent from the client and parsed correctly. Still, I get different session IDs in the `context` apollo callback. What I'm doing wrong? I have already spent hours finding the issue but no success. I hope there is someone out there with more experience to help me tracking the issue.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I'm encountering the same problem